# How do I add string with auto increment value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I add a string with auto-increment value in SQL Server?

```
create table date (sno int 'emp_'+ identity(1,1))
```

I need following as output

```
emp_1
emp_2
```

Comment: autoincrement string? huh? `a`, `b`, `c`, ...?

Comment: Sounds like something a trigger would be useful for.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: It looks like the goal is for the the `sno` column to hold values as follows: `emp_1`, `emp_2`, `emp_3`, etc... Is this correct?

Answer (score 11):

1. Define your table with a normal `INT IDENTITY` column
2. Add a **computed column** that merges string and `ID` together:

Something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
       (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        EmpID AS 'emp_' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED, 
        ......
       )
```

This way, your `ID` column is a normal IDENTITY column, and `EmpID` will contain `emp_1, emp_2, emp_3, ......, emp_42, ...`

By making it a **persisted** computed column, the data is actually stored on disk and doesn't need to be re-calculated every time you access the table. Also, when persisted, you can easily put an index on that computed column, too

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any string as autoincrement

Lets think you have a table

```
|- id -|- name -|
|-  1 -|- Utku -|
|-  2 -|- Gopi -|
```

Lets select them as emp_1,emp_2

```
SELECT CONCAT("emp_",id) AS emp_id,name
FROM table
```

Result:

```
|- emp_id -|- name -|
|-  emp_1 -|- Utku -|
|-  emp_2 -|- Gopi -|
```

Comment: concantenating in every query is a bad idea.  Please look at @marc_s's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using computed column MSDN

```
CREATE TABLE Yourtablename
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    InvoiceID AS 'INV'+ right('000000' cast(ID as varchar(20),7)
);
```

Comment: Are you sure this answer is for this or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468567/create-column-which-increases-from-last-index