# SQL Server + Increment a non primary key field in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a non primary key TicketNo. field in my SQL server database where the format is fixed but consist different formats e.g. Vou001..Vou002, TKO001...TKO002. for every record that comes in, I need to increment the last no. so the record after Vou002 is Vou003, after TKO004 is TKO005. How can I perform this task without using some sort of record counting method. Since the table will consist of different kinds of TicketNo Format I believe it's not possible to get the last table value and add on it. Please kindly advice. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to use trigger gor this; else I don't see any other way to do this.

Comment: Another problem you have to consider (after you solve this one) is what should happen after ticket `Vou999` is issued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each code here consists of 1 parts: a prefix (`Vou`, `TKP` etc) and a number.

- The number can be generated via a sequence emulation (or directly in SQL Server 2012)
- The prefix can be stored separately or appended to the sequence before writing to the table

Using any kind of MAX or "roll your own" won't be concurrency safe for 2 concurrent/overlapping calls even with lock hints. And these will reduce performance too.

This DBA.SE question shows how to emulate sequences in SQL Server: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/emulate-a-tsql-sequence-via-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have a look here, the issue was not exactly the same, but I guess that's a good start : [How do I add string with auto increment value in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170950/how-do-i-add-string-with-auto-increment-value-in-sql-server)

Comment: +1 yes- that's really the only reliable way to do it - let the database handle the autoincrementing, and just add your prefix to it.

Comment: @marc_s: can be done by emulating a sequence per prefix. MS have an article on it (see dba.se link)

Comment: For my case, the field format can be different, it actually retrieves the formatting from another table which has a 'formatting' Field column.