# Specialized counter field in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Want to have a counter field that starts with a character followed by a number as a regular counter, but the counter should start with x number of zeros.

Example:

```
L00001
L00002
L00003
```

Is it possible to construct such counters in sql server?

**Update:**

It should be auto generated counter values that is incremented by 1 when a new row is added. The number of rows in the table is never going to be as large as L99999.

Its Sql server 2012 express im using.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Do you want auto generated counter values in a column(Table design) when you add new values OR you just want a column in your select queries ???

Comment: And what should happen after `L99999` is reached?

Comment: It should be auto generated counter values that is incremented by 1 when a new row is added. The number of rows in the table is never going to be as large as L99999.

Comment: Sql server 2012 express

Comment: What determines the leading character? Is it always "L", or is it dependant upon something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible trick, use a computed column:

```
--DROP TABLE MyTable
CREATE TABLE MyTable
 (
   MyTableId   int  not null  identity(1,1)
  ,MyTableKey as 'L' + right('00000' + cast(MyTableId as varchar(5)), 5)
    persisted
    constraint PK_MyTable
     primary key clustered
  ,SomeData    varchar(50)
 )
```

Column MyTableKey is calculated based on the identity column and actually stored within the table (persisted, as opposed to calculated on the fly--so it's only calculated when a row is first inserted). This allows it to be indexed, and I set it as the primary key sonce nothing should ever reference the "Id" column.

Some sample data:

```
INSERT MyTable (SomeData) values 
  ('First')
 ,('Second')
 ,('Third')
 ,('Etc')

SELECT *
 from MyTable
```

Comment: I think `right('00000' + cast(MyTableId as varchar(5)), 6)` should actually be `right(..., 5)` for his case, but in any case, this is a nice solution. +1

Comment: Whoops, I missed that -- originally had the "L" inside the `right` statement, and didn't adjust the length when that proved a mistake. The answer has been adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server, this may be what you're looking for as far as the counter goes (not sure if you need that too):

```
ROW_NUMBER ( ) 
    OVER ( [ PARTITION BY value_expression , ... [ n ] ] order_by_clause )
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

For example,

```
SELECT
    SomeColumn,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) AS Number
FROM
YourTable
```

As far as padding a value with zeroes, you can do something like:

```
SELECT 
    'L' + REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(YourId)) +
        CONVERT(varchar(255), YourId)...
```

`REPLICATE` repeats the specified value N times, N being the number you provided. And if it's a potential scenario, you should also consider what will happen if the length of `YourId` exceeds 5 (your return value would be `NULL`).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx

Comment: Since, according to your update, you need to do this at row insert, this solution no longer applies. Philip Kelley's answer addresses what you need.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create a function which return varchar and no input require

inside function
get the max value from table remove @i from it such that you have only int left and store in  @max increment by one

```
Declare @i char(1)='L'
Declare @max int=1112 

select @i+replicate('0',4-len(@max)+1)+casT(@max as varchar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with STUFF function:

```
DECLARE @Number INT = 123
SELECT 'L' + STUFF('00000', 5-LEN(@Number)+1, LEN(@Number) , @Number)
```

Comment: OK, you need autogenerated counter... Please see at: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170950/how-do-i-add-string-with-auto-increment-value-in-sql-server) , user @marc_s has a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

hi david use this query for create your table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emp](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) ,
        [AutoGeneratedColumn]  AS ('L'+right(replicate('0',(5))+CONVERT([varchar](5),[ID],0),(5)))
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: @david in above query AutoGeneratedColumn is your counters Coloumn.