# Create column which increases from last index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to generate a column for InvoiceID. and I want to keep the formate of this column like this

```
INV0000001,
INV0000002,
.
.
.
.
INV0000010,
INV0000011,
.
. and so on.
```

As you can see this column is increasing with last index.
How can i do this.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have searched, but couldn't find, how to increase a number like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `computed column` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188300.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE Yourtablename
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceID AS 'INV'+ right('000000'+cast(ID as varchar(20)),7) PERSISTED
);
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83552)

For more info on why you need to make your computed column as `persisted` 
check [*here*](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/03/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and%C2%A0performance/)

Comment: +1 - If your table is used frequently in queries then you may want to weigh up the benefits of making the computed column persisted too. That way you won't incur the cost of the calculation for each query. It is a trade off of storage vs performance

Comment: @Fireblade ,  just for some clarity. Won't the above script then increment with last digit but still have '000000' ? Example; 0000009 would increment to 00000010 instead of 0000010 ?

Comment: @PKirby - No it wont thats why this part is used `right('000000' cast(ID as varchar(20),7)`

Comment: @MrMoose - Completely agree with you. Updated

Comment: @Fireblade: would you check your query again. I'm getting error, 
`CREATE TABLE Invoice
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    InvoiceID AS 'INV'+ right('000000' cast(ID as varchar(20),7) PERSISTED
);`

Comment: @Fireblade:still getting same error, `Incorrect syntex near cast`

Comment: @AmitKumar - missed comma check now

Comment: @Fireblade: I have tried that. same problem . after putting `,`, it is saying right function requires 2 argument. as i can see, you are passing 2 argument but don't know why it is still giving this error.

Comment: @AmitKumar - Sorry dont have SSMS to validate my answer check now paranthesis was at wrong place. Try now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83501/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-fireblade).

Comment: @AmitKumar - Finally its working. Added demo too

Answer (score 1):

try, this one :- (completely dynamic)

```
Declare @NextInvoice    Int = 0

Select  @NextInvoice = Isnull(Max(Cast(Replace('INV0000011','INV','') As Bigint)),0) + 1

Select  'INV' + Left('0000000', (Len('0000000') -Len(@NextInvoice))) + Cast(@NextInvoice As Varchar(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work for u

```
SELECT
    INV + right('000' + an_auto_increment_column, 3)  AS InvoiceID
    FROM yourTable
```