# How to insert loop value in SQL Server insert-select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

`ORSeries` where the last official receipt is temporarily saved:

```
|ORSeries|
+--------+
| 1000   |
```

`Collections` where users issued with an official receipt will be saved:

```
|   OR   |  ID    |  Date  |
+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |
```

`Users` where users without an official receipt are saved:

```
|  ID    |  Date      |
+--------+------------+
|  0001  | 08-10-2019 |
|  0002  | 08-10-2019 |
|  0003  | 08-10-2018 |
|  0004  | 08-10-2018 |
|  0005  | 08-10-2018 |
```

I want to issue an official receipt to the users dated 08-10-2018. What I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO [Collections] (OR, Name, [Date])
    SELECT
        (SELECT SeriesNo + 1 FROM TempORSeries),
        Name,
        [Date]
    FROM 
        ORSeries
```

Expected output:

```
|   OR   |  ID    |    Date    |
+--------+--------+------------+
| 10001  |  0003  | 08-10-2018 |
| 10002  |  0004  | 08-10-2018 |
| 10003  |  0005  | 08-10-2018 |
```

However, all the users received the same official receipt number.

My query returns:

```
|   OR   |  ID    |    Date    |
+--------+--------+------------+
| 10001  |  0003  | 08-10-2018 |
| 10001  |  0004  | 08-10-2018 |
| 10001  |  0005  | 08-10-2018 |
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The columns in the SQL code don't match the table definition or sample data. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is some reason you couldn't use an **[Identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)**, Sql Server 2016 and later support **[SEQUENCES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)**.

You should get rid of the `ORSeries` table completely and either replace it with a new Sequence or convert the `OR` column in the `Collections` table to an identity. Here is the Sequence example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ORSequence START WITH {current sequence value + 1 here};
```

Then the INSERT statement will look like this:

```
Insert into [Collections] 
(
    OR,
    ID, 
    [Date]
)
SELECT
    NEXT VALUE FOR ORSequence,
    ID,
    [Date]
FROM Users WHERE Date = '20181018'
```

Both options get rid of the need to use a transaction to control updating the old `ORSeries` table — which you probably weren't doing before, and were therefore at risk of two sessions using the same OR numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number + SeriesNo`

```
begin transaction;

declare @SeriesNo int = (case 
                            when not exists(select 1 from Collections) 
                               then (select SeriesNo from TempORSeries)
                               else (select max([OR]) from Collections) 
                         end);

Insert into [Collections] 
    select
        @SeriesNo + (row_number() over (order by (select 1))),
        [Name],
        [Date]
    from
        ORSeries
    where 
        [Date] = '2018-08-10';

commit;
```

[Online Demo With SQL Server 2012 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3bedca6112ea3d3aca6a862893746512)

[image]

---

> How can I update my ORSeries table with the last issued official receipt ?

This is a new question, I recommend using `auto increment concat` to avoid multiple connection problem. Please read :

[tsql - How do I add string with auto increment value in SQL Server? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170950/how-do-i-add-string-with-auto-increment-value-in-sql-server)

Comment: how can I update my ORSeries table with the last issued official receipt ? and, I want to issue official receipt to 10-08-2018 only, not including year 2019.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin transaction

insert Collections
select t1.[OR] + row_number() over(order by t2.ID), t2.ID, t2.Date
from ORSeries t1
cross join Users t2
where t2.Date = "08-10-2019"

update ORSeries
set [OR] = (select MAX([OR]) from Collections where Date = "08-10-2019")

commit transaction
```